# SGML formating Issue

Tags: c#

I have an requirement to read the SGML file and replace if the symbol like comma(,) or full stop (.) then I need to change the symbols and save with the same SGML file itself but I am facing the format issue after replacing the content.
Below is my code and my final output would be store with the same .sgm format.
The below code is working but after replacing the values the output format is differs. Can you suggest for this scenario

Main method:

string resultValue = HTMLToEntity(ReplaceSGML(sbContent.ToString()));

```
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(resultValue.ToString());
        SgmlReader reader = new SgmlReader();
        reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.All;
        reader.CaseFolding = Sgml.CaseFolding.ToLower;
        reader.InputStream = sr;
      
        
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        w.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
        w.WriteStartDocument();
        reader.Read();
        while (!reader.EOF)
        {
            w.WriteNode(reader, true);
           
        }
       //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Output\test.sgm", );
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
```

Method : ReplaceSGML

```
 private static string ReplaceSGML(string html)
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(_xmlEnglishPath);
    XmlNodeList resources = xml.SelectNodes("root/data");
    _htmlEnglishDictonaries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    _htmlEnglishDictonaries.Add("&#59;", "{After1Space}"); // replacing semicolon into {After1space}
    _htmlEnglishDictonaries.Add("&#58;", "{Before1Space}"); // replacing colon into {Before1Space}
        _htmlEnglishDictonaries.Add("&#46;", "{Before1Space}"); // replacing . into {Before1Space}
    
    string line = string.Empty;
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(html);

    while (reader.Peek() > -1)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        foreach (var events in _htmlEnglishDictonaries)
        {
            if (line.Contains(events.Key))
            {
                //  Rule should be implement
                //  <!-- Replacetext 1.{After1Space}, 2.{Before1Space}, 3.{NoSpace}, 4. {After1LetterCaps}  -->
                int idx;
                if (events.Value.ToLower().Trim() == "{after1space}")
                {
                    idx = line.IndexOf(events.Key) + events.Key.Length;
                    if (line[idx].ToString() != " ")
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(events.Key, events.Key + " ");
                    }
                }
                if (events.Value.ToLower().Trim() == "{before1space}")
                {
                    idx = line.IndexOf(events.Key);
                    if (line[idx].ToString() != " ")
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(events.Key, " " + events.Key);
                    }
                }
                if (events.Value.ToLower().Trim() == "{before1space},{after1space}")
                {
                    idx = line.IndexOf(events.Key);
                    if (line[idx].ToString() != " ")
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(events.Key, " " + events.Key + " ");
                    }
                }
                if (events.Value.ToLower().Trim() == "{nospace}")
                {
                    idx = line.IndexOf(events.Key);
                    if (line[idx].ToString() != " ")
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(events.Key, " " + events.Key);
                    }
                }
                if (events.Value.ToLower().Trim() == "{after1lettercaps}")
                {
                    idx = line.IndexOf(events.Key) + events.Key.Length;
                    if (line[idx].ToString() != " ")
                    {
                        if (line[idx + 1].ToString() != " ")
                        {
                            line = line.Replace(events.Key, " " + events.Key + line[idx + 1].ToString().ToUpper());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            line = line.Replace(events.Key, " " + events.Key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return line.ToString();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Beyond compare to find differences between old and new files.  Then post differences if you cannot figure out yourself.  You may have slight format differences because XML white spaces are not required to be exactly the same since white spaces are ignored except in the innertext.

Comment: But I wanted to make automate the process for more files with different symbols.

Comment: You need to be more specific and what issues you are having.  I'm not sure why you are using HTML methods on a file that is XML.  XML there are only five special characters that need to be substituted while HTML has a lot more.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references